# Email do PHPMailer enviado com sucesso, mas não recebido Amazon SES

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpmailer

Estou usando o PHPMailer Laravel do Amazon SES. Minha conta não está em uma sandbox . Meu problema é quando tento enviar email no painel admin Laravel no meu site para meus clientes. Sou informado que foi enviado com sucesso. Mas, quando verifico a caixa de entrada, spam e lixeira do meus clientes o email não foi recebido. Quando faço teste no meu site usando o formulário público consigo enviar o email e receber na minha caixa de entrada com sucesso. Antes eu nem conseguia enviar e receber o email pelo formulário público do meu site, porque dava erro: `` Get set up but error is appearing: stream_socket_enable_crypto (): Peer certificate CN = `signsofforex.com 'did not match expected CN =` email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com' `` Consegui resolver esse erro entrando no Cpanel, WHM, SMTP Restrictions, a opção estava ativada, eu desativei. Resolveu o problema do formulário público mas agora estou com problema no painel admin. Utilizo o servidor Vultr para hospedar o site e o WorkMail da amazon para receber os emails.

mail.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mail Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
    | sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
    | your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
    |
    | Supported: "smtp", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill", "ses",
    |            "sparkpost", "log", "array"
    |
    */

    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
    | applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
    | the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
    |
    */

    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Port
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
    | users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
    | stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
    |
    */

    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Global "From" Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
    | the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
    | used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
    |
    */

    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | E-Mail Encryption Protocol
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
    | the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
    | transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
    |
    */

    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Server Username
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
    | set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
    | connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
    |
    */

    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),

    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sendmail System Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
    | the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
    | been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
    |
    */

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Markdown Mail Settings
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If you are using Markdown based email rendering, you may configure your
    | theme and component paths here, allowing you to customize the design
    | of the emails. Or, you may simply stick with the Laravel defaults!
    |
    */

    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

];
```

.env

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=live
APP_KEY=base64:2t/r95eojKWVGAlH44ZV5mu5qa5Q+aexXY/F1A/Y=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_INSTALL=false
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost/softwarezon_signal_mod5

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=sinaisde_**
DB_USERNAME=sinaisde_**
DB_PASSWORD=**********

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=AK9A1APWPA1C6R******
MAIL_PASSWORD=BTsZ3PRE+************
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

PURCHASE_CODE=SOFTWAREZON_DEFAULT_CODE
BUYER_USERNAME=softwarezon
```

services.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Third Party Services
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This file is for storing the credentials for third party services such
    | as Stripe, Mailgun, SparkPost and others. This file provides a sane
    | default location for this type of information, allowing packages
    | to have a conventional place to find your various credentials.
    |
    */

    'mailgun' => [
        'domain' => env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN'),
        'secret' => env('MAILGUN_SECRET'),
    ],

    'ses' => [
        'key' => env('SES_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('SES_SECRET'),
        'region' => 'us-east-1',
    ],

    'sparkpost' => [
        'secret' => env('SPARKPOST_SECRET'),
    ],

    'stripe' => [
        'model' => App\User::class,
        'key' => env('STRIPE_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('STRIPE_SECRET'),
    ],

];
```

Comment: Se envia e não recebe entra em contato com a empresa que te fornecer o servidor de e-mail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize o serviço SES via API e não como SMTP. 
1 . Crie um usuário IAM para o Amazon SES.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2 . Defina as permissões do usuário
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

3 . Instale o guzzle para fazer requisições HTTP para a API do SES:

```
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

4 . Instale o SDK da AWS para PHP

```
composer require aws/aws-sdk-php
```

5 . Configure o arquivo ***config/services.php*** com os dados do usuário IAM criado.

```
'ses' => [
    'key' => 'your-ses-key',
    'secret' => 'your-ses-secret',
    'region' => 'ses-region',  // e.g. us-east-1
],
```

6 . Modifique o driver de e-mail do laravel no arquivo ***.env***

```
MAIL_DRIVER=ses
```

Utilizando a API da AWS o envio de e-mails não depende de bibliotecas do PHP ou de configurações do servidor de hospedagem.

Para mais informações acesse a [documentação de e-mails](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mail#driver-prerequisites) do Laravel.